# Connecting to derby via I.P. Address fails

Tags: java, database, jdbc, derby

When I print the I.P. address of the system using `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`, I get `user-VAIO/192.168.1.3` .
 Now, when I connect to derby using `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mydatabase;create=true`, it connects without any errors 
but when I connect the same using `jdbc:derby://192.168.1.3:1527/mydatabase;create=true`, 
it fails giving me the following exception:-
`java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server 192.168.1.3 on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you try adding IP in host file

Comment: @www.sblog.in how do you do that. Any link for it ?

Comment: Check your firewall. Add the exception in firewall. It is a common problem in windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start your Derby Network Server, you provide a value for the '-h' argument. You might not realize you are doing this, if you are using the packaged StartNetworkServer.bat file, but look inside the batch file, and you will see the -h argument there.

The batch file comes provided with the syntax '-h default' when you download Derby from the Apache website.

But you can change that, to say, for example, '-h 192.168.1.3', and then your Derby Network Server will accept connections that specify 'jdbc:derby://192.168.1.3/my/database'.

Note that if you want to accept such connections from other computers on the network, you will also have to adjust your Windows Firewall rules, as by default it will prevent such connections.

Comment: I shifted from java db to mySQL server as it got connected with I.P. without any firewall blocking. Plus I do not even need to the start the networkserver each time when I start the program.